# Error loading d3-geo-projection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to copy this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3711652 - code and javascript libraries - locally. I'm having issues pointing to a local version of the the d3-geo-projections library (d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js).

On Chrome's console, I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'aitoff'

The error above doesn't happen if I point to the d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js version hosted at d3js.org.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Download the version that works from the website?

Comment: I've done that - and that works, but I don't want my code to rely in an external resource. I'd like to have all necessary libraries locally.

Comment: Are you saying that when you download the remote library that works and include the downloaded version it doesn't work?

Comment: Exactly. Sounds very basic, but I've tried for quite a while and it doesn't work. The paths are correct. So the only change is from pointing to the d3js.org hosted version to my local one, which I copied from d3js.org.

Have you ever created a project using a local version of the d3-geo-projection library?

Comment: Are you loading the scrpts in exactly the same way? In particular, are you specifying `charset="utf-8"`?

Comment: Yes, I literally change that one line of code. It goes from functional to broken.

The example sets the charset on the the meta tag.

Comment: Try specifying the charset when loading the script, in the `<script ...>` line.

Comment: No luck, exactly the same error. I've tried running in tomcat, running outside tomcat (creating a folder on my desktop, putting all the files and double clicking the index.html), same error occurs.

Comment: Hi Lars, the issue was that I opened http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js on my browser and copied the code. As soon as I did a wget specifying the same location, the correct content was copied. I believe the javascript code I was copying before was being displayed incorrectly in the first place. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was accessing http://d3js.org/d3.geo.projection.v0.min.js directly on my browser, and what I was copying was already broken. After I opened my console and used the "wget" command, the correct content was copied and the example started working.